# Why two-way bound component updates twice in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, object, svelte, two-way-binding, svelte-component

I have a `<select>` bound to **activity.status** like so:

```
<script>
import Dropdown from './Dropdown.svelte'
let activity = {
    id: 1,
    projectName: "Test Project",
    lead: {id: 10, value: "Unassigned"},
    status: {id: 3, value: "Closed"},
    statusDetail: {id: 15, value: "Missing Budget"}
    }

let statusOptions = [
        { id:1, value:"Open"},
        { id:2, value:"On-Hold"},
        { id:3, value:"Closed"}
        ]

$:console.log(activity.status);
</script>

<select bind:value={activity.status}>
    {#each statusOptions as option}
        <option value={option} >{option.value}</option>
    {/each}
</select>

<!-- <Dropdown  options={statusOptions} bind:selected={activity.status}/> -->
```

The `$:console.log(activity.lead)` fires every time I update the `<select>`.

But once I use the `<Dropdown/>` instead, it fires twice. Here is the component:

```
<script>
export let selected = {} 
export let options = [{id:0, value: "No Options..."}]
</script>

<select bind:value={selected}>
    {#each options as option}
        <option value={option} >{option.value}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

I don't have huge knowledge in svelte, but I studied the API and searched on stackoverflow. The only thing I didn't try was emitting a custom event. But that seems like a bit of extra code and unelegant. I don't mind the double update but it seems stupid. So I would like to know: **Why does that happen?** Should I emit custom event instead? Or did I make some basic mistake?

Thank you, Filip

Answer (score 0):

my issue suddenly disappeared. I suspect it has something to do with single top level element becasue it disappeared after I removed other top level elements in my component. However, when I put them back, it still worked so I cannot recreate the issue anymore.

[Svelte doesn't require you to have single top level element like Vue or React](https://svelte.dev/blog/write-less-code#Top-level_elements) so it was probably some mistake I made but don't remember.

Also in the [official tutorial by Svelte](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings), they advise people to use component bindings sparingly. I am posting the answer if anybody faced the same issue. Good luck!